# Accessing javascript file from Node JS - Beginner

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have several `javascript` files in my `js` directory. How can i add these files in nodeJS.

For example if I am to access a particular `javascript` file from a `HTML` document I use the following code :

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

But, how can I access this same file (`js/main.js`) in nodeJS ?

**UPDATE**

In `NODE JS`
var express = require('express');

```
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
require('js/main.js');
```

The error what i get:

> Error: Cannot find module '/js/main.js'

Comment: use `require('/your file path')`;

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_require_id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your server.js add following lines and check it once.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname ));
```

this set your current directory as your root directory and put your js folder in root level. add comment if you don't find your answer.

Comment: The JS files are in the folder PUBLIC/JS. I am still not able to find it

Comment: Then put following lines app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Comment: remove require('js/main.js'); it is not required for load javascript in html

Answer (score 1):

There should be 2 cases

**1 - Include Javascript file in html file.**

In this case, you can include your javascript file in your HTML file by writing the following code in your HTML File.

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

**2 - Use One Javascript file code in other javascript file of your nodeJS server app code.**

NodeJS has the concept of modules to write your code in multiple files.

You can export the code of main.js file as module with 
`module.exports` and use this code in any other js file by including following line

```
var mainModule = require('/path/main.js');
```

For more details about the modules in nodeJS, you can go through the documentation https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: in main.js file. You need to export the module with

Comment: module.exports = ExportObject

Comment: Where ExportObject is the Object of main.js file what you want to use in other file and export it.

Comment: Also, Please take care of the path while importing the module.

Comment: If you are still facing the issue, Please post the directory structure and main.js file code. Will help you.